# Why does my SharePoint task have no related item?

Tags: workflow, tasks

I have a workflow that starts a process.  As part of this it creates a task and emails the users.  On one of the pages I have, I am retrieving the tasks and then getting the related items and associating it to the items on the page.  The problem is that occasionally there is a task that gets created that won't have a related item.  This causes me to not be able to associate it with what should be the related item.  Why is this related item not being assigned?

Comment: Is it possible this task was related to an item that has since been deleted? Deleting items doesn't delete its related tasks.

Comment: @ErinL No, the item is still there.